# Is it possible to stop execution of a .NET self-contained single-file when run command "help myproject" in Linux?

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a .NET6 console project and published a self-contained single-file for Linux-x64. It works fine when I just execute it. But when run "help myproject" it shows information and starts execution of the file. Is there any way to prevent its execution in this case?